# Webdriver / Selenium (Python): How to find URL of link that doesn't have @href

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, href

When a hyperlink is defined in HTML with a @href, the `find_element_by_XXX.get_attribute()` can be used to extract it's URL.

What is the equivalent for when a link is defined in CSS?

Example:

```
<input value="Buscar con Google" aria-label="Buscar con Google" name="btnK" jsaction="sf.chk" type="submit">
```

Comment: I don't think you can define a link in css. It is a form. please provide the whole form

Comment: What do you plan to do with the URL? Are you simply storing it or do you have other plans?